# Is there any service or API to render the saved pbix power BI file on web ? without using power bi web or azure services?

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have created a visualisation in power BI desktop , i need to publish my file into any web server without registration in power bi web or azure services .
i am asking if there is any available API or server or any web service to use it and open the 
".pbix" file on it.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is not sensitive/confidential you can use the [publish to web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web) option, other wise you will have to use the Power BI Embedded service, using an 'A' SKU.

These are designed for creating your own portal, so you can basically create your own version of the Power BI Service. So you need to create a portal with it’s own sign up/login page, user management etc. and users don’t need a Power BI License to view reports. You’ll need one for creating reports, but for report consumers, nothing is needed. These dedicated capacity SKU’s can be paused so you can reduce the daily/monthly cost as they are billed by the hour and these SKU’s are purchased via the Azure Portal.

This way you can distribute Power BI reports via a web app, and not require the users to login to Power BI or have a license

Hope that helps point you in the right direction